# Change button text based on cell value in each table row - Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, events, dynamic

I have a HTML table that is showing data from DB. A [status] column shows the status of each record as "AVAILABLE" , "BOOKED" or "ON-HOLD". the last column of table is [ACTION] column which contains a BUTTON. If the status of row = "Available" then button text should be "BOOK". Likewise if the status = "BOOKED" or "ON-HOLD" the the button text should be "VIEW". I have applied css successfully via jquery that changes the background-color of status column based on the text in the cell as mentioned above but the same code is not working for button text.

**HTML**

```
<tr id="data_row">       
   <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $Project; ?></td>
   <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $Sector; ?></td>
   <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $Category ;?></td>
   <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $Plot_title ;?></td>
   <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $App_date ;?></td>
   <td class="align-middle text-center"><?php echo $Customer ;?></td>
   <td class="align-middle text-center" id= "status"><?php echo $Status ;?></td>
   <td class="align-middle text-center">
       <button type="button" name="edit" id="<?php echo $Plot_ID; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm edit_data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalform" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Book</button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#myTable tr#data_row td#status').each(function () {
    switch ($(this).text()) {

        case "Booked":
            $(this).css({"background-color":"#eeac88", "color":" #7a3b2e"}); // (WORKING FOR CSS)
            $(".edit_data").text("View"); // (NOT WORKING FOR TEXT CHANGE)
            break;

        case "on-Hold":
            $(this).css("background-color","#fefbd8");
            $(".edit_data").text("View");
            break;
    
        default:
            $(this).css({"background-color": "#c5d5c5", "color":"green"});
            $(".edit_data").text("Book");
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: First thing you need to fix is you can't have repeating ids in a page. They are like an address and are unique by definition

Comment: Then you need to get the one within the current row. `$(this).closest('tr').find('.edit_data').doSomething()`

Comment: Worked like a charm. I replaced the code in your comment. You said Unique Ids. you meant ID=STATUS ?  I am new to JQuery. Can you please elaborate what was I missing in my knowledge. Obliged.

Comment: `$(".edit_data").text("Book");` does same thing to every matching selector in the whole  page. Going to the closest row and finding the one in that  row only affects that specific instance

Comment: OK. That makes sense. I need to learn more about JQuery Traversing. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Remember that pattern. It's very common when you have repeating items in a page

Comment: Logic is you have status cell instance in the each loop , traverse up to closest `<tr>`  from that instance and look inside that `<tr>` for the other element

Comment: Excuse me for writing on a matter already solved. I gave a study to Traversing yet could not develop an understanding of you solution. After hours of thinking I got a clue that Traversing is relative to the current document object being assigned an event & function. hence you started your selector with $(this) and went a level above by closest('tr') thereby broadening the search scope and then again going down by find('.edit_data') targeting the specific class. In my understanding so far, we must start traversing from current object and then go relatively up or down or sideways. am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(".edit_data").hmtl("View");
```

Or put a `<span>` inside the button to access it with .text() method

Comment: This will change all in the table and not do anything significantly different than using `text()`

Comment: html() and val() will not work since the button element is used not and input. plus <SPAN> is also not working.

Comment: If there is problem with looping then CSS would also not work but the CSS is coloring each cell correctly based on the value contained in that cell.